# How to change datepicker default settings in Wordpress using Avada theme?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, flatpickr

The Avada theme seems to use `flatpickr` as the default datepicker for their Avada Forms, but it is not possible to change the default configuration using the Avada Builder.

[image]

I would like to play around with the optional parameters as described on https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/. As a minimum, I would like to set a minimum date (`minDate`) such that the date of yesterday cannot be picked. The problem is that I lack quite some knowledge on Javascript and the behind-the-scenes of Wordpress. I have tried to edit the `flatpickr.js` file located in `wp-content/plugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/library/flatpickr.js`, but this was not permitted and I also do not know if this is how the default settings should be changed at all.

What is the correct way of setting the `minDate` for `flatpickr` in Wordpress using Avada theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research and with help of Avada support, the following steps need to be taken to make modifications to the `flatpickr` datepicker.

1. Add a child theme (in this case the Avada Child Theme)
2. Copy the `flatpickr.js` script located in `/wp-content/plugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/library`
3. Make desired modifications in the copy of `flatpickr.js`
4. Put the modified version of the `.js` file in the Avada Child Theme directory `wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme`
5. Modify the `functions.php` file of the Avada Child Theme by adding this piece of code:

```
function ab_dequeue_script() {
    Fusion_Dynamic_JS::dequeue_script( 'fusion-date-picker' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'ab_dequeue_script', 100 );

function ab_flatpicker_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'fusion-date-picker',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/flatpickr.js',
        [ 'jquery' ],
        '1',
        true
        );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ab_flatpicker_enqueue', 999);
```

6. Select the Avada Child Theme in Wordpress.

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you can only use jQuery to set the minimum date.
you will select the input field ID by jquery and put the flatpicker settings.
For ex.

```
<input type='text' id='form' name='form'>
<script>
jQuery( '#from' ).flatpickr({
    minDate: "today"
});
</script>
```

Also, you can add the jQuery code in Avada options on Wordpress dashboard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use following for Avada and Wordpress:

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('#your_input_selector').flatpickr({
    minDate: "today",
    defaultDate: "today"
    });
});
</script>
```