# Flatpickr format date for UK users DD-MM-YY - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, forms, date

I'm currently having an issue changing the date on an Avada form to UK format dd-mm-yy. The form uses a date module called flatpickr and having tried a number of different options to get the date to the UK to show as DD-MM rather than MM-DD, I've reached a dead end. The WordPress site itself is set to the UK.

Avada has a token system you can paste into the form field called 'date format' but there isn't an option for my issue. https://flatpickr.js.org/formatting/

At the bottom, there is a bit of javascript which looks like it could be what I need but I've no idea how to get this into my WordPress site:

{
dateFormat: "Y-m-d\Z", // Displays: 2017-01-22Z
}

I've tried pasting code into the date format field and nothing changed.

Here's a link to my page https://artiziancatering.co.uk/innholders-hall/

Update: I found a thread on here [How to change datepicker default settings in Wordpress using Avada theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67756330/7834825) and have managed to download the flatpickr.js file, I've also put some code into function.php, which apparently enables me to edit the flatpickr.js

I don't know any javascript and it's driving me crazy trying to solve what must be a simple thing.

Any assistance is gratefully received.

Jo